# Regular expression to match multiple lines after occurence

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex:

```
^lineC:\n\t(.*)
```

and I have a multiline string

```
lineA:
    line1
    line2
    line3

lineB:
    line4
    line5
    line6

lineC:
    line7
    line8
    line9
```

that matches **line7** only. But I need to return **line7**, **line8** and **line9**.
I can do it like this

```
^lineC:\n\t(.*)\n\t(.*)\n\t(.*)
```

but of course it won't work if I have more lines under *lineC*. Any ideas?
[link with example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aK8Gxy/1)

Comment: `^lineC:\n((?:\t[^\n]*\n?)*)`? You'll have to split the matches after the fact -- that's the nature of repeated capturing groups

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oJMV3Q/2 - LMK if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
test_str1 = """
lineA:
    line1
    line2
    line3

lineB:
    line4
    line5
    line6

lineC:
    line7
    line8
    line9
"""

test_str2 = """
lineA:
    line1
    line2
    line3

lineB:
    line4
    line5
    line6

lineC:
    line7
    line8
    line9
    line10
    line11

lineD:
    line12
    line13
    line14
"""


p = re.compile(r'(?m)^lineC:((?:\n\t(?:.*))*)')
m = re.findall(p, test_str1)
m
['\n\tline7\n\tline8\n\tline9']

m = re.findall(p, test_str2)
m
['\n\tline7\n\tline8\n\tline9\n\tline10\n\tline11']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

reg = re.compile(r"(\w+):\n((?:\s+\w+(?:\n|$))*)")

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = {
        name: lines.split()
        for name, lines in reg.findall(f.read())
    }

pprint(data)
```

Outputs:

```
{'lineA': ['line1', 'line2', 'line3'],
 'lineB': ['line4', 'line5', 'line6'],
 'lineC': ['line7', 'line8', 'line9']}
```

---

#### Breakdown of `r"(\w+):\n((?:\s+\w+(?:\n|$))*)"`

Captures 2 major groups: `(\w+)` and `((?:\s+\w+(?:\n|$))*)`.

All other groups are set to non-capturing to make `findall` easy to work with.

```
(\w+)                     Capture a word in group 1
:\n                       Group 1 followed by :\n
(                         Start the capture for group 2
    (?:                   Start a non capturing group for the repeated content
        \s+\w+            Starts with whitespace followed by a word
        (?:\n|$)          Followed by a new line or the file end
    )*                    Non capturing group repeats multiple times
)                         End group 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally repeat a newline and a tab after the first match inside capture group 1, to have all the lines in group 1.

Note that `.*` could also match an empty part after the `\n\t`

```
^lineC:\n\t(.*(?:\n\t.*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `lineC:\n\t` Match  `LineC:` a newline and tab
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` Match any char 0+ times
  - `(?:\n\t.*)*` Optionally repeat a newline, tab and the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7Hkzx/1)

Example code

```
import re
 
regex = r"^lineC:\n\t(.*(?:\n\t.*)*)"
 
s = ("lineA:\n"
    "   line1\n"
    "   line2\n"
    "   line3\n\n"
    "lineB:\n"
    "   line4\n"
    "   line5\n"
    "   line6\n\n"
    "lineC:\n"
    "   line7\n"
    "   line8\n"
    "   line9")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['line7\n\tline8\n\tline9']
```